# Inno Setup Chinese Language File not working

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I found this unsupported Chinese .isl file (for translation in Inno) on the Inno Setup website.

http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/istrans/ChineseSimp-12/ChineseSimp-12-5.1.11.isl

as well as this "traditional" version

http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/istrans/ChineseTrad-2/ChineseTrad-2-5.1.11.isl

When I compile in the Inno Setup Compiler IDE, It says

```
Parsing [Languages] section, line 23
   File: C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Languages\Chinese.isl
Parsing [LangOptions], [Messages], and [CustomMessages] sections
   Messages in script file
```

When I run the setup.exe file, It simply acts as if it was not included in the [Languages] area at all. For example, when I have English Chinese and French as languages available, it only shows the English and French languages.

I don't really know where to go from here but I need to figure out why this isn't working... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the ansi version of Inno setup and your machine can't display that language.
See the [ShowUndisplayableLanguages](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_showundisplayablelanguages.htm) directive or use the unicode version.